# clustering approach to identify temporal "states" within time-series in R

Tags: r, time-series, clustering, multivariate-analysis

I am working on a problem where I have a multiple time series, each with a size of a 100 steps, each being described by a 8 variables variables. I want to identify "states" within each time series, where a state would reflect some cluster that is learned from the spatiotemporal pattern of values of the 8 variables.

So so far most options point me towards dynamic time warping `DTW`, but I am not really interested in grouping the full time series (e.g. timeseries 1, time-series 2, etc each of 100 steps* 8 variables, into a group of similar vs dissimilar timeseries), which is what approaches like dtw seem to do in my understanding.

What I really want is to find states within each timeseries. say within timeseries 1 (containing 100 steps and 8 variables), I want to find pieces of time that reflect different clusters, they might have different durations, shapes, etc.

What I have tried so far is to use `k-means` clustering for each timeseries, where I use the 8 variables as features to the kmean algorithm, and for a single timeseries I would get something like figure 1 when `k = 3` [image: Figure 1]

the lines represent the 8 variables and the shaded colors represent the k-means clusters I identified. I would then do this for all timeseries. While this seems to work for this case, I am worried about its appropriateness, specifically, because the clusters will be biased toward the means of the variables, and the kmeans doesn't really exploit the temporal structure explicitly.

for a context, these data represent body movement trajectories as defined by the magnitude and speed of a number of sensors. I want to find certain states like movement initiation, sustainment, etc, which I think can be captured by clusters that represent these states.

Any suggestions of whether this is okay, or other sensible approaches, that I could implement in `R` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hidden markov models?

Comment: @Sycorax could you elaborate please

Comment: The tag wiki is a good place to start: [tag:hidden-markov-model]. The question with the HMM tag and the highest score also lists a number of resources for learning about HMMs.

Comment: I mean I do get the general idea for hidden-Markov models, but I don't fully see how it would address finding substates within a time series, rather than grouping known time-series sets into a set of latent states. I browsed other questions with HMM and didn't see a direct translation to my problem

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're making between "clustering" (which you state you want to do) and "grouping known time-series sets into a set of latent states" (which you claim is a reason HMMs aren't suitable). Moreover, you explicitly state that "kmeans doesn't really exploit the temporal structure explicitly," which is a problem that HMM solves because it is a model for sequential data. Also, grouping together time steps in time series data together is "clustering" for a time-series, so it seems to fit what you ask in the question.

Comment: so yes, I understand that HMM should exploit the temporal structure better. What I mean with the distinction is that with the clustering I want to do, I don't know how much of a given time series with form a cluster, whereas the HMM approaches I have seen would take say 5 time series of a 100 steps each and cluster the "whole" time series into a group of 3 and 2 for example, whereas I want to know how each of the 100 steps within each time series cluster into k states, if that makes sense, I added a clarification to the question before the last paragraph if it helps.

Comment: I think your understanding of HMMs is mistaken. An HMMs infer a latent state for each time step within a single time series.